# Find Object in List which is Data Bound to ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

This question has probably already been answered, but i couldn't find a solution during 30 minutes of research.
The situation is as follows:
I am working on a C# Windows Forms project.
I have a Form called 'viewMain'. [image: Part of the layout of 'viewMain']
Also these two classes are important:
[image: class 'Auftrag'][image: class 'AuftragErp']

With the winforms designer i added two bindingSources to the Form. One for objects of `Auftrag` and one for objects of `AuftragErp`. The DataSource for `auftragBindingSource` is set to an Instance of `Auftrag`. The DataSource for `auftragErpBindingSource` is set to the `AuftraegeErp` property of the `Auftrag`-Instance.

Now i can begin describing the problem. The ComboBox `Auswahl` on the Form is bound to `auftragErpBindingSource` and therefore always reflects the objects in the `AuftraegeErp` list. When i click the button on the form i want to get a reference to the currently selected object in the combobox.

I found that this can be achieved by using `uftragErpBindingSource.Current`.
But since the BindingSources are private i can't access them from the `Auftrag` Instance.

And i don't want to get this reference in an eventhandler of the form, since then i still would have to pass it on to the `Auftrag` instance. And if i where to do that, then i feel as though i could go without data binding altogether. The main reason for me to use data binding is not having to worry about keeping the objects and the gui synced.

So basically i have a list in a class. This list is bound to a comboBox. From inside of the class i want to get the object from the list which is currently selected in the comboBox.

I am thankful for every answer and hope that somebody can help me.

Edit for clarification:[image: diagram of use case] This Drawing shows the relation between the classes and the GUI. After the user has made his selection with the combobox he can click the Button. The onClick eventhandler then calls the 'doSomething' method. This method needs the selected object to function. There are multiple ways how the method can get the necessary object. I have shown two in the drawing. a) The method gets the objects from the list in its own class, or b) The method gets the object by using the .Current Property of the bindingSource on the Form.
I want to use approach a, because then i wouldn't have to pass any Variables or Objects between the Model and the View. Data binding alone would make sure that the GUI is always up to date. But i don't know how to implement approach a.

Comment: I'm trying,but I don't understand your problem. What's wrong with getting the selected object using the `SelectedItem` property of your `ComboBox`?

Comment: While your issue looks well described, it is very difficult to quickly understand what your code is doing and how it is structured because of your native language variable names. It would be easier for us if all your variable were in english too.

Comment: I have edited my original post to add a drawing and some additional explanation. I'm sorry for using native language variable names. I wont do so in the future. But right now i don't have the time to translate them.